# Fixed header while scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the header of a table in the middle of a page, but since the page is huge, I want to fix the header to the top of browser while I scroll down for the page...

So my question is: How do I set header to be normal, until the user scrolls down and the top border of header touches the browser border, where it should stay fixed on that position, no matter how much further down the user scrolls?

Comment: use **.scroll()** of jquery and set at specific scroll point of window and either add a fixed position class to the target or do **.css()** to the target elem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let me explain as to how this could be done.

### Steps

1. Find your table header, and save its `position`
2. Add a listener to the window's `scroll` event.
3. Check the window scroll against your table header position

   1. If the position < window scroll - add a class to fix the table header
   2. Else, reset the css to behave like a normal header.

I've posted a fiddle that [you can find here](http://jsfiddle.net/jbY6X/1/).

### Code sample

### HTML

```
<div class='lots_of_stuff_in_here'> ... </div>
<table>
    <thead id='my_fixable_table_header'>
        <tr>
            <th>My awsesome header number 1</th>
            <th>My awsesome header number 2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Content</td>
            <td>Content</td>
        </tr>
        // much more content
    </tbody>
</table>
```

### Javascript

```
// Just so you get the idea behind the code

var myHeader = $('#my_fixable_table_header');
myHeader.data( 'position', myHeader.position() );
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var hPos = myHeader.data('position'), scroll = getScroll();
    if ( hPos.top < scroll.top ){
        myHeader.addClass('fixed');
    }
    else {
        myHeader.removeClass('fixed');
    }
});

function getScroll () {
    var b = document.body;
    var e = document.documentElement;
    return {
        left: parseFloat( window.pageXOffset || b.scrollLeft || e.scrollLeft ),
        top: parseFloat( window.pageYOffset || b.scrollTop || e.scrollTop )
    };
}
```

​

Comment: -1: Header cells should match the widths of the cells in the same column.

Comment: I was looking at your example when trying to build my own and needed to modified your fiddle a bit so that the colums stayed the same as the headers when scrolling. I added some code that measures the headers and applys this to the first table row so that when you move the headers to be fixed with jQuery the width of the columns stay the same as the headers. http://jsfiddle.net/jbY6X/145/

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for a horizontally oriented "sticky box" that follows you down the page as you scroll.

Here is a walkthrough that explains how to create this effect for a sidebar: http://css-tricks.com/scrollfollow-sidebar/

I modified the code to work with a generic example that spans the width of the page:

#### HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="head">HEAD</div>
  <div class="header">Table Header</div>
  <div class="content">Content</div>
  <div class="footer">Footer</div>
</div>​
```

#### CSS:

```
.wrapper {
  border:1px solid red;
}
.head{
  height: 100px;
  background: gray;
}
.header {
  background:red;
  height:100px;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  top:0px;
  margin-top:100px;
  position:absolute;
}

.content {
   background:green;
   height:1000px;
}

.footer {
   background:blue;
   height:100px;
}
```

#### jQuery:

```
$(function() {

    var $sidebar = $(".header"),
        $window = $(window),
        offset = $sidebar.offset(),
        topPadding = 0;

    $window.scroll(function() {
        if ($window.scrollTop() > offset.top) {
            $sidebar.stop().animate({
                top: $window.scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding
            });
        } else {
            $sidebar.stop().animate({
                top: 0
            });
        }
    });

});​
```

​This will animate the header block into view when you scroll beyond where it originally appears.

[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/radiatorsounds/Bavvw/)

Comment: Consider showing some code on how it will work. If/When these links no longer work, your answer will not be useful.

Comment: I need something like this with jQuery. Is that possible with CSS?

Comment: Thanks @MikeSmithDev, I added an example. Nutic, let me know if this makes sense.

Comment: This is working, but only for <div> tags. I can't make it to work with <TH></TH>

Comment: Add the `header` class to the containing `tr` of the `<th></th>`.

Answer (score 0):

you may try to enclose the bottom elements under the header in one div then add class to that div set overflow to auto

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are looking like this Header Fix [**Demo**](http://tinkerbin.com/cH1FK535)

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="header">Header Fix</div>
<div class="content">Content</div>
<div class="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
  border:1px solid red;
}

.header {
  background:red;
  height:100px;
  position:fixed;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  top:0;

}

.content {
   background:green;
   height:1000px;
}

.footer {
   background:blue;
   height:100px;
}
```

Comment: Yes and no. I know how to do this, but problem is that when I open page, i have like 200px of content before that table. Then when I scroll 200px down, I want that table header to stick on top, not to stay 200px from top while scrolling.

Comment: @Nutic so please post your complete code how you are doing than we will be able to tell you the solution bitterly.

Comment: http://tinkerbin.com/rJK990rM
example: it looks like that. I want when I scroll down, that HEAD part goes up, and dissapear, and red one stays fixed at TOP, not fixed and starting position.

Answer (score 0):

for keeping the position fixed of any block element,you need to use the absolute or the fixed property in the display attribute of style,but dont forget to give enough space and break to the top elements otherwise it will go under the header section.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
 if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100){  
    $('header').addClass("sticky");
  }
  else{
    $('header').removeClass("sticky");
  }
});
```

css:

```
header.sticky {
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  background: #efc47D;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a full working version using fixed headers, footers and columns!

Apply the classes for position relative, very important, otherwise the fixed column will overlap the header and footer, then define the classes at the table level where needed: "sticky-table"(mandatory), "sticky-header", "sticky-column", "sticky-footer", than call function "applyStickyHeaders". That's all!

```
$(function(){
    applyStickyHeaders();
});
```

Full example:

https://jsfiddle.net/pintilies/6zLyxewg/4/

Tested in IE, FireFox and Chrome.